Remove incomplete ip neighbour record
Ubuntu 22.04
I have an IPv6 record marked as INCOMPLETE:
$ip neigh
xxxx::xxxx dev eth0 INCOMPLETE  

Trying to delete it as
$sudo ip neighbo del xxxx::xxxx dev eth0

does not actually delete it since ip neigh reports it in the same way. Is there a way to drop the INCOMPLETE neighbour record?

Why do you need to delete it? The record will be updated if NDP succeeds.

@vidarlo exactly delete, like make it disappear from ip neigh listing.

What issue does its existence cause?

It feels very much like an X-Y Problem. In general, ask how to solve your problem, not some intermediate step.


does not actually delete it since ip neigh reports it in the same way

No, I'm 98% sure that it does delete the record, but during the non-zero time it takes you to check ip neigh again, the system has already added a new record for the same address. What you see in the ip neigh report is not the old record; it is a new record with the same values.
If you watch ip monitor neigh (or maybe watch -d -n .1 "ip neigh | grep $addr") you will likely see the old record being deleted and almost immediately a new one being created, with the same parameters.

Why does the system add the record back? For the same reason it added the original one: it has some IP packets that need to be delivered to that address.

Why is the record being added in 'INCOMPLETE' state? That's the normal state while the system is waiting for a neighbor discovery response (in this case an ICMPv6 Neighbor Advertisement solicited). If there was a host with this address, it would transition to 'REACHABLE' as soon as the ICMPv6 NA was received.
If there is no such host, the entry will transition to 'FAILED' in a few seconds and all queued packets will be flushed. However, the OS will immediately restart the process for as long as it keeps receiving new packets destined for that address, so you'll almost instantly see a new 'INCOMPLETE' entry in its place.



This smells like an XY problem.  There is almost no reason to delete this entry.
The ip neighbor command is displaying the system ARP cache.
An incomplete entry indicates an ARP broadcast request has gone out to query the ethernet address of the target IP address, but no reply has been heard yet.
The normal ways an incomplete entry is deleted are:

a reply is received, and the INCOMPLETE is replaced with the target machine physical address.
the entry times out and the system deletes it.

This happens fairly quickly, so there's no need to delete an incomplete entry.  And an incomplete entry will not block the ip address -- when a reply is received, it will automatically resolve.
I have on occasion deleted complete entries when there was an IP conflict (two physical machines replying to one ip) and I wanted the other one, but this should really never happen.
Presumably the kernel keeps the incomplete entry around so that it has somewhere to store the timers relevant to sending out ARP retries, and preventing it from sending out a storm of ARP requests for every packet going to that unknown ip address.
So the only reason to delete the entry is that you want to immediately send out another arp...and the retry timers are short enough this shouldn't be necessary and probably isn't humanly possible to manually delete the entry faster than the retry timer anyway.
So you are fixing the wrong problem.  Don't bother deleting this entry, find out why the remote machine isn't responding on the network!   Or find out why there is a local process attempting to contact a non-existent ip address.
